# Add an icon to a node in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-node

I would like to add an icon on the border of a node. I can do it easily for one node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw] (A) {content};
        \fill(A.west) ++(0.1,0)--++(-0.1,-0.1)--++(-0.1,0.1)--++(0.1,0.1)--++(0.1,-0.1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But for convinience, I would like to make a style doing the job. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{symbol/.style={...}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,symbol] (A) {content};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `\fill` isn't part of the `\node`, but rather both are separate `\path`s. You could make a shape which includes the icon, but that uses `\pgfdeclareshape` (page 1126).

Comment: I guess the `\pgfdeclareshape` is a good choice, it seems convenient to use. Sadly my knowlege in pgf, is not sufficient now. But from the answers below, it seems to be the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `pic` with `[pic actions]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[diamond/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (.1,0)--(0,.1)--(-.1,0)--(0,-.1)--cycle;
}]
\path 
(0,0)    node[draw] (A) {content A}
(A.west) pic[fill=red]{diamond};

\path 
(4,0)    node[draw] (B) {content B}
(B.east) pic[fill=blue!50,draw=magenta]{diamond};

\path 
(2,-1)    node[draw] (C) {content C}
(C.north west) pic[fill=white,draw]{diamond};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do such things with the `append after command` key (see the pgfmanual v3.1.4 on p. 151) but since you want to fill the extra thingy but not the node, you also need a path picture, so it is a bit complicated given the outcome. This defines a style `diamond node` that can be used like

```
\draw[fill] node[diamond node] (A) {content};
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[diamond node/.style={draw,fill,
path picture={
\fill[white] (path picture bounding box.south west)
 rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
\fill (path picture bounding box.west) ++(0.1,0)--++(-0.1,-0.1)--++(-0.1,0.1)--++(0.1,0.1)--++(0.1,-0.1)--cycle;},
append after command={
(\tikzlastnode.west) 
++(0.1,0)--++(-0.1,-0.1)--++(-0.1,0.1)--++(0.1,0.1)--++(0.1,-0.1)--cycle}}]
        \draw[fill] node[diamond node] (A) {content};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The seemingly simpler option of using `\pgfextra` inside the `append after command` is a trap...